# Analyzing existing apex and components

Tags: apex

I’m new to salesforce and given a task of analyzing existing apex, trigger, lightning  components and aura.

All of the code is in sandbox, there is no IDE used in our company.

What is the best way to analyze the code and understand the functionality, and to write test class for all the salesforce components?

Comment: without an IDE, this task is way harder than it needs to be

Answer (score 3):

I would start by installing e.g. VSCode and SFDX (see e.g. [Set Up Visual Studio Code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-visual-studio-code) and pull the components out of the org onto my machine.

These tools are free.